# Why does my table look this way?

Tags: tables

Why is the input text not inside the cell?

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|cc}
    \hline
    Input&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1input.png}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2input.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    \hline
    {\footnotesize GroundTruth}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1true.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2true.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    {\footnotesize ConvLSTM}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1rnn.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2rnn.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    {\footnotesize VarConvLSTM}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1vrnn.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2vrnn.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    {\footnotesize E3DLSTM}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1e3d.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2e3d.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    {\footnotesize Ours} &\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1ours.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2ours.png}\\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Prediction on the moving MNIST dataset. We obtain visually pleasing results even on complex example shown in right. Furthermore, our results indicate less blur.}
\label{fig:qualitativemnist}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found the solution that is to use raisebox

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{rcc}
    \raisebox{1\height}{\footnotesize Input}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1input.png}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2input.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    \raisebox{1\height}{\footnotesize GroundTruth}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1true.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2true.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    \raisebox{1\height}{\footnotesize ConvLSTM}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1rnn.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2rnn.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    \raisebox{1\height}{\footnotesize VarConvLSTM}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1vrnn.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2vrnn.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    \raisebox{1\height}{\footnotesize E3DLSTM}&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1e3d.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2e3d.png}\\[-0.18cm]
    \raisebox{1\height}{\footnotesize Ours} &\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1ours.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2ours.png}\\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Prediction on the moving MNIST dataset. We obtain visually pleasing results even on complex example shown in right. Furthermore, our results indicate less blur.}
\label{fig:qualitativemnist}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```